# Find a element by class from parent without querySelector or getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

Following my code:

```
<div id="test">
    <div>
       <div class="find_me"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I don't want to use querySelector or getElementsByClassName, how to create a while loop for each element in the id 'test' until you find the div with the class 'find_me'?

Comment: Why? Do you need to support legacy browsers? If so, why aren't you using a library like Sizzle (aka jQuery selectors)?

Comment: But instead of including an external file powerful, is not better one thing that does exactly enough?

Comment: No. Don't reinvent the wheel. Use a library, and move on to solving real problems.

Comment: Why -1? Which part of rules I violated?

Comment: _"Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.** Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the_ expected _results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly

1) Get the children of test element. (here the variable is **`child`**)

```
var child = document.getElementById('test').children;
```

2) Iterate each of them, since it also needs to be iterated once again I'm iterating its children.  (Not sure why JS has such a structure) (variable is **`children`**)

```
 var children = child[i].children;
```

**Final code:**

```
var child = document.getElementById('test').children;
for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
    var children = child[i].children;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i].className == "find_me") {
            alert("Yup, here I am");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm including a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NJGXB/1/), so that you can check the console the reason for the ITERATIONS.

Hope you understood my logic.

(I agree with @MattBall)Try *jQuery*, this has clean methods like `.filter(), .find()` etc.,  You will love once you get your hands dirty on it.

Comment: @user2886519 I'm glad I was able to help :)